# Error running a program using subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a tool which returns me some info about the machine I am running on.On the normal command line it would be something like -

> sudo   /path-to-tool-directory/tool   arg

and this works fine .Now when I break this up and include this in my python script as

> result = subprocess.call (["sudo /path-to-tool-directory/tool","arg"])

it throws me an error

> subprocess.py in line XYZ ,
>    in _execute_child
>   raise child_exception
>   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

any clue what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

When using the subprocess module you need to provide the `call()` function with a **list** of command line arguments.  Taking your example above:

```
result = subprocess.call (["sudo /path-to-tool-directory/tool","arg"])
```

This won't work because `"sudo /path-to-tool-directory/tool"` is a single list item.  What you need is **all** items to be individual list items:

```
result = subprocess.call (["sudo", "/path-to-tool-directory/tool", "arg"])
```

This should successfully run and terminate leaving the return code from sudo in `result`.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Gives the reasons for OP's problem pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Split off the call to sudo (for all the reasons that @zzzrik elaborates on above):

```
>>> result = subprocess.call (["sudo /usr/bin/python","/home/hughdbrown/Dropbox/src/longwords.py"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> result = subprocess.call (["sudo", "/usr/bin/python","/home/hughdbrown/Dropbox/src/longwords.py"])
[sudo] password for hughdbrown:
```

See? The second one is working because I get prompted for a password.

Comment: nope doesnt work for me .Infact I made it even simpler and I tried just this in my file.py "g = subprocess.call([ "/usr/lib/vim"])" and that gave me the same exception

Comment: Is vim actually in /usr/lib? Mine is in /usr/bin.

Comment: I would start by calling `which vim` (or whatever you want to test) and then putting that exact path as the first argument to `subprocess.call`. That way, you know that you will not get "no such file or directory".